# How to get method's request in springmvc

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

I have the next method:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/busqueda/basica", method = {RequestMethod.POST,RequestMethod.GET})
public String busquedaBasica(HttpServletRequest request,
                             HttpServletResponse response,
                             ModelMap modelMap,
                             @RequestParam("nombreBasica") String nombre){
    ...
}
```

Is there any way to get the method's request, POST or GET?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the `HttpServletRequest` has a [`getMethod()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getMethod%28%29) that returns a `String` value representing the HTTP method.